# VSCode Flutter - stop tracking Flutter repo changes

Tags: git, flutter, visual-studio-code

I can't figure out when this started, but suddenly I find my repo tracking all my changes just fine, but...

There's another repo open - like the entire Flutter source - and my source control is tracking thousands of changes.

Is there some easy way to turn this off?  I can't seem to find it.

TIA

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No. I really like Flutter, but I ended up doing a pure web app instead. 

Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. In VS Code hit Ctrl+Shift+P
2. Type and select `User Settings`
3. In the search field enter `git.AutoRepositoryDetection`
4. select field to `false`

[image]

Answer (score 32):

The solution is to add the path to the flutter repo to the `"git.ignoredRepositories"` list either in the user or workspace settings.

```json
"git.ignoredRepositories": [
        "/path/to/flutter"
    ]
```

I had to reload/restart the vscode window for it to take effect.

--

An alternative is to change `git.AutoRepositoryDetection` from `true` to `subFolders`. This will keep scanning the current folder and sub folders but avoids tracking flutter.

[image: git.AutoRepositoryDetection]

Comment: Works flawlessly, unfortunately needs a restart in vscode

Comment: "git.autoRepositoryDetection": false. Even simpler as you don't need path

Comment: i hate vscode. how to do without it?

Comment: @David this is not a good idea because usually users want git repos within the workspace folder to be detected.

Comment: @felix-ht, you are right but that was excactly what I wanted to do in my case