# Flutter - VSCode source control shows change for a file outside the project

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, version-control

[image]

Why am I seeing this even though the project is not linked with any git repository?

The change is in the file ~flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle.
(Note: I had changed this file to change the minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion.)

However, it is still outside the project and shouldn't be shown as a change.

How do you get rid of this? It's a new project and I want to push it to a new repository.

Comment: "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: Is this related?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587947/vscode-flutter-stop-tracking-flutter-repo-changes